Why is the subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ of index $2$ expressible in terms of the sum of $\zeta_p$ to the power of all quadratic residues mod $p$?
Let $p$ be an odd prime, $\zeta_p = e^{2 \pi i / p}$. I've been playing around with calculating the intermediate fields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.
I know that $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) / \mathbb{Q}) = \langle \sigma \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} /(p-1) \mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, and hence we have a subfield of index $2$, since the group has a subgroup of index $2$, $\langle \sigma^{(p-1)/2} \rangle$.
I've tried to write the corresponding subfield as $\mathbb{Q}(\sum_i \zeta_p^{a_i})$ for some exponents $a_i$, and noted the following pattern



$p$
Corresponding subfield
Non-zero quadratic residues mod $p$




$3$
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$
$1$


$5$
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5 + \zeta_5^4)$
$1,4$


$7$
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^4)$
$1,2,4$


$11$
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{11} + \zeta_{11}^3 + \zeta_{11}^4 + \zeta_{11}^5 + \zeta_{11}^9)$
$1,3,4,5,9$



So, it seems that the corresponding subfield is
$$\mathbb{Q} \left( \sum_{a: \, \left( a/p \right) = 1} \zeta_p^a \right).$$
How can we explain why this pattern emerges? I don't understand how to link this to the theory of quadratic residues.

It is called a subfield of degree $2$ (over $\mathbf Q$), or more commonly a quadratic subfield.
To see a number $\alpha$ in $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ is quadratic over $\mathbf Q$, we can do two things: (i) show $\alpha$ is fixed by the subgroup of index $2$, so $[\mathbf Q(\alpha):\mathbf Q] \leq 2$, and (ii) show $\alpha \not\in \mathbf Q$, so $[\mathbf Q(\alpha):\mathbf Q] > 1$.
We will apply this to $\alpha$ being your sum, which I'll denote
$$
S =\sum_{\substack{a \not\equiv 0 \bmod p \\ (\frac{a}{p}) = 1}} \zeta_p^{a}.
$$
Since ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)/\mathbf Q)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$, its subgroup of index $2$ is the nonzero squares mod $p$, so this subgroup is the automorphisms determined by $\sigma_{c^2} : \zeta_p \mapsto \zeta_p^{c^2}$ as $c^2$ runs over the nonzero squares mod $p$. We compute
$$
\sigma_{c^2}(S) = 
\sigma_{c^2}\left(\sum_{\substack{a \not\equiv 0 \bmod p \\ (\frac{a}{p}) = 1}} \zeta_p^a\right) = 
\sum_{\substack{a \not\equiv 0 \bmod p \\ (\frac{a}{p}) = 1}} \zeta_p^{ac^2} = 
\sum_{\substack{a \not\equiv 0 \bmod p \\ (\frac{a}{p}) = 1}} \zeta_p^{a} = S
$$
since the change of variables $a \mapsto a/c^2$ when $a$ runs over the nonzero squares mod $p$ is a permutation on that set. Thus $[\mathbf Q(S):\mathbf Q] \leq 2$. Why is $S \not\in \mathbf Q$? We can use $\{\zeta_p,\zeta_p^2,\ldots,\zeta_p^{p-1}\}$ as a $\mathbf Q$-basis of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ (this is just multiplying the terms in the usual $\mathbf Q$-basis $\{1,\zeta_p,\ldots,\zeta_p^{p-2}\}$ by $\zeta_p$) and the way $1$ is written in that basis is
$-\zeta_p - \zeta_p^2 - \cdots - \zeta_p^{p-1}$, which includes all terms in our basis, so rational numbers are rational multiples of that way of writing $1$ as a sum over the whole basis, which means rational numbers are $\mathbf Q$-linear combinations of our basis with all coefficients being equal. The number $S$ does not have that form: $S$ is a sum over only half the terms in our basis.
That was an answer to your question directly using the sum you asked about. There is another (more common) way using the Gauss sum
$$
G = \sum_{a = 1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\zeta_p^a. 
$$
This is a sum over all the terms in our basis with half the coefficients being $1$ and half being $-1$, so $G \not\in \mathbf Q$.
A standard Gauss sum calculation, making no use of Galois theory, is
$$
G^2 = (-1)^{(p-1)/2}p = \pm p,
$$
so $G$ is quadratic over $\mathbf Q$ without using Galois theory,
To relate $G$ to $S$, consider
$$
-1 = \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \zeta_p^a.
$$
When you add the sum $G$ to this, the terms on the right where $a \bmod p$ is not a square will cancel, so summing the formulas for $G$ and $-1$ gives us
$$
G -1 = 2\sum_{\substack{a \not\equiv 0 \bmod p \\ (\frac{a}{p}) = 1}} \zeta_p^a = \sum_{b=1}^{p-1} \zeta_p^{b^2} = 2S.
$$
Thus $G = 1 + 2S$, so $G$ being quadratic over $\mathbf Q$ implies $S$ is quadratic over $\mathbf Q$ as well.
Remark. Using ramification in algebraic number theory, it is possible to show the quadratic subfield of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ is generated by the square root of $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$ without using explicit sums over any basis at all.
Looking here at Theorem 3.8, along with Examples 3.2 and 3.9, tells you how to construct a generator $\alpha_H$ of the subfield of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ fixed by each subgroup $H$ of ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)/\mathbf Q)$, which is isomorphic to $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$: you can use $\alpha_H = \sum_{\sigma \in H} \sigma(\zeta_p)$. The quadratic subfield of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$, for example, corresponds to the subgroup $H$ of index $2$ in the Galois group $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$, which is the squares in $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$. In this case $\alpha_H$ is the sum of $\zeta_p^{b^2}$ as $b^2$ runs over the different nonzero squares mod $p$ (each just once, not twice with $b^2$ and $(-b)^2$).
